# re-connect my project with svn

Tags: eclipse, svn

I use eclipse 3.6.2, I didn't have subversion plugin installed in eclipse, I have the source files for a project, I imported those files as a new project in eclipse, the source files have .svn files with them.

after that I installed subversion plugin subversive, how can I make eclipse connect my project to svn?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just Check out a clean copy from the server? If you don't have local modifications, then you're done! If you do have local modifications, you can just merge them into the clean copy. There are many tools that can easily help you with that task.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can that by re importing the projects. ie. First delete the projects from you package explorer without deleting the contents on the disc, then import the projects again. Which may work. As I don's have a set up with svn repository I couldn't try it out.